# Representing a number with one byte in python?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, raspberry-pi, arrays, wiringpi

A byte of data can represent values from o to 255. However, when I declare a byte objct in python and give it an integer less than 255, the size is still huge.

```
>>a=b'9'
>>sys.getsizeof(a)
>>18
>>a=b'19'
>>sys.getsizeof(a)
>>19
>>a=b'019'
>>sys.getsizeof(a)
>>20
```

This data needs to go to an SPI device via the wiring-pi library for raspberry pi. The original C function which is wrapped in python by the library takes as input, a char array, which are perfectly byte sized. however, in python, the function takes a `b''` as its argument. The message `'Hello World!\n'` is 13 bytes if represented as a char array. declaring the string in python and encoding it with `str.encode()` gives an object that has a size of 30 byte.

```
>>s ='Hello World!\n'
>>s=s.encode()
>>sys.getsizeof(s)
>>30
```

How can I fix this such that '1' is a representation of the number '1' and has a size of one byte (represented as 00000001 bits), and that the string `Hello world!\n` is in fact an array of 13 bytes?

Comment: You can't. Welcome to Python. `b'\x01'`

Comment: What does it matter if the actual object in memory is a few bytes larger than its contents? If you write it somewhere (a binary file, a pipe to another process, a serial port to a microcontroller, ...) you only write the actual content bytes (i.e., 13 bytes in the case of `b'Hello world!\n'`).